Play and write piano music
How would someone write a 3/4 bar correctly if it included a 2 and 1/2 beat (tied or as one note) and an 8th note.

You would need one more sixteenth note or rest to make it a full measure. Where would that go? Beginning of the measure, between the 2.5 and1/16-note, or at the end of the measure?

Would this bar have any rests? 2x1/4 + 1/2x1/4 + 1/16 add up to less than 3 quarter notes (your notes end up a 16th note shy).

Or, if there aren't any more notes or rests and it's the very last bar or, even more, the last bar inside a repeat, it might complement a pickup in the beginning (of that repeat / section / whole thing). (Unlikely to be a pickup.) Or it might not actually be notated correctly; mistakes happen. Is this a test question, an exercise to fill in the gaps, or something you've found in a score?

@Dekkadeci - do your sums add up? Or are mine wrong?

How is this question a duplicate of the other question about 5/4 time?

@JanaeJanzen what is the actual issue? You have 2 1/2 beats plus a 1/2 beat which makes a full measure of three beats in 3/4 time. Those durations add up, so where is the trouble?

@MichaelCurtis The question doesn't say there's any trouble. It asks how one would write it correctly, so I take it that the asker isn't sure of something about the notation.

@Divizna, there should be some kind of trouble. Otherwise what is the point of asking a question? But the OP already described the way to notate it in their answer. They should post an image of their score, or describe what exactly they aren't sure about.

@MichaelCurtis 1. The point of asking a question doesn't need to be "there seems to be something wrong, how on earth come?", it can also be "I want to do this, what's the proper way to go about it?" 2. Yes, ideally the asker would have expressed their question more clearly, but asking questions the right way is also a skill. It's their very first post here. Don't scare them away by demanding perfection.

Asking the OP for clarification is not "scaring them away."

As I'm sure you're aware, 2 beats plus half-a-beat (an 8th note or quaver) plus a 16th (or semi-quaver) don't quite add up to three beats.  We're a 16th short. So, leaving out special circumstances where an incomplete bar might be permissible,  the answer is that you do it by adding a 16th rest somewhere in the bar.
But that's a bit obvious.  Perhaps you're asking how to group the notes?  I'd suggest as in my second example.
This answer still stands now you’ve corrected the arithmetic in the question! Just change the 16th + rest for an 8th.


Given the lack of accurate information in the question I think the rest can also be placed between the two notes, making the 16th note on the “a” of 3.

The edit very much changes the question! So much so that I think you should have asked a new question rather than edit the existing one. This isn't about not matching the time signature at all.
If you want to know whether you should connect the eighths with a beam or write them as separate,

then as far as I know, both versions would be fine. I think the version with a beam would be the more common first choice, and the one with flags could be preferable if the last note was starting a new phrase or something, but it's pretty much up to your judgement.
If you want to know how you should write the 5/8 tone, half note tied to eighth is pretty much the only option here. Notation that would write it as one note doesn't exist (or if it does, it must be rare).
If it was eighth and then 5/8, you'd need to write it the other way around: eighth tied to half. Basically, the seam between the tied notes should align with the seam between the beats.



...if it included a 2 and 1/2 beat (tied or as one note) and an 8th note.

You did not say what the actual problem is, and your wording is a little unclear.
Why mix durations in beat lengths (2 1/2 beats) with note values (8th note)? You can still do the arithmetic that way, but it makes me wonder if somehow that is the source of your confusion.
Are you giving the order of the notes?
In the order you listed, you can do it with a tie...

If the order isn't important, it could be this...

These two give equivalent durations, but put the half note in between the eighths. This is not ideal, because it makes it hard to read the beats...

Are you looking for a way to dot a note to get 2 1/2 beats and avoid using a tie? That won't work. Dotting will always give a duration less than double the value of the dotted note. So any dotting of a quarter note will be less than 2 beats and not enough. Dotting a half note will give 3 beats and is too much.
Did you mean using a rest to get 2 1/2 beats "as one note?"

Technically that is not notating a duration of 2 1/2 beats with another 1/2 beat.
